# Haskell DB recommendations?

Tags: database, haskell

There is a lot of databases, but I feel something different needed for Haskell. Like Erlang has it's own DB, Mnesia. Please recommend some good DBs for Haskell.

Answer (score 11):

There are various frameworks for Haskell available, HDBC being the most popular.

HDBC is the database abstraction library, which allows you to use many popular databases, even Oracle or DB2. See [Chapter 21. Using Databases](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html) in Real World Haskell.

Comment: There's also an [interface to CouchDB](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/CouchDB) for Haskell.

Comment: That version is a couple of years old.  Your best bet, if you decide to use CouchDB, grab the newest fork on github which is, at the moment, https://github.com/tbh/haskell-couchdb

Answer (score 7):

I would advise you to choose the database depending on the type of data you want to store in it, rather than the language your system is implemented in.

Of course, this presupposes that bindings for the database exist in the language.

Comment: ...or you have the time to write bindings

Answer (score 7):

Since the question mentions Mnesia, I'll mention Haskell's equivalent: [AcidState](http://happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/AcidState.html). It's a fast and flexible nosql database written in Haskell that has support for representation of native and user-defined Haskell types (that link shows you some quick how-tos, including implementing a hello-world blog).

There's more recent documentation on [their wiki](http://acid-state.seize.it/), and I've personally used it [here](https://github.com/Inaimathi/goget/blob/master/Model.hs) in the implementation of a small web app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres I would recommend [Opaleye](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye).  Disclaimer: I'm biased because I wrote it!

Comment: This is not a DataBase but a DataBase library

Comment: True, though most answers seem to have interpreted OP as asking for a library recommendation.